# Get multiple values from one column with jsonb type

Tags: postgresql

I need to get `drXY, fromXY`and `distInM` but they are all in 1 column.
I can't select `additional_data` as a column to get all list because it contains not only this information.

On the picture below you can see what exactly columns looks like to this event.

[image: Columns]

I haven't tried anything because I don't have any mind how to do this kind of request in postgres

I expect to see this 2 coordinates and radius like the output of the request.

Data example from the additional_data column

```
{"cd":{"Query":"drXY:50.36212158,30.93627930,fromXY:50.36899347,30.92296243,distInM:1217"}}
 {"cd": {"Query": "drXY:50.35106277,30.95141602,fromXY:50.33421340,30.98074794,distInM:2805"}}
 {"cd": {"Query": "drXY:50.35106277,30.95141602,fromXY:50.33421340,30.98074794,distInM:2805"}}
 {"cd": {"Query": "drXY:50.34796524,30.95644951,fromXY:50.33421340,30.98074794,distInM:2309"}}
 {"cd": {"Query": "drXY:50.35132980,30.95157051,fromXY:50.33421340,30.98074794,distInM:2817"}}
```

Comment: Do you need those values as three individual columns? Or do you just want the content of the `Query` key?

Comment: As three individual columns

Comment: Like the next step, this data is going to be used in scrypt which is requesting this parametres to put it in ORS and return the distance calculated by map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the answer

```
    with derived as (
        select substring(query from '(drXY:[0-9]+\.[0-9]+,[0-9]+\.[0-9]+)') as drxy,
               substring(query from '(fromXY:[0-9]+\.[0-9]+,[0-9]+\.[0-9]+)') as fromxy,
               substring(query, '(distInM:[0-9]+)') as dist
        from (
          select additional_data -> 'cd' ->> 'Query' as query
          from stat_event where
          additional_data -> 'cd' ? 'Query' and
          value is null and
          action = 'ProposalShown' and
          created between '2019-08-04' and '2019-08-05'
        ) t
    )
    select *
    from derived
    where drxy is not null
  and fromxy is not null
  and dist is not null;
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit tricky as the actual Query content is not stored as a proper JSON value (which would make this extremely easy). I think the shortest way to do that is to use regex once the query is extracted:

```
select substring(query from '(drXY:[0-9]+\.[0-9]+,[0-9]+\.[0-9]+)') as drxy,
       substring(query from '(fromXY:[0-9]+\.[0-9]+,[0-9]+\.[0-9]+)') as fromxy,
       substring(query, '(distInM:[0-9]+)') as dist
from (
  select additional_data -> 'cd' ->> 'Query' as query
  from the_table
  where additional_data -> 'cd' ? 'Query'
) t;
```

Online example: https://rextester.com/YDKB3888

Comment: This column have similar type of query but some of them may be with the drXY null and some other values which is not used in my data.

Comment: Idea is to get only type of query which i post upper without anything else

Comment: @SemyonKolesnikov: then filter out those rows where the keys don't exist. See my edit